# Subnet mask and Default Gateway

Tags: subnet, gateway

Since subnet masks defines the network, so does it defines default gateway's IP address?

Ex. if a class A subnet 255.0.0.0 is define, you set your default gateway to also be like 10.0.0.0 to 254?

Comment: The gateway is of course inside the network or it becomes unreachable. So what is the question?

Comment: Gateway is a specific address, not just any available address

Comment: @John what is the difference between "a specific address" and "any available address". The specific address has to be one that is available. Perhaps you mean the gateway is not a range of addresses. though the OP didn't necessarily say it was.

Comment: Gateway is within the network. Workstations do not need a gateway but servers and routers do need one and it is normally provided upon setup.

Comment: @John so your comment there ignored my comment to you then, ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong on loads of fundamental levels, and has been a while since I looked into networking.

You write

> "a class A subnet 255.0.0.0 "

That looks more like a subnet mask than a subnet.

You write

> "you set your default gateway to also be like 10.0...."

Only if your subnet is 10....

Also classes haven't been used in many many years.. even years ago when I looked into it, classes were only taught in some networking courses but weren't in use and hadn't been in years.

Also, you wouldn't give your gateway a subnet address(.0), which is another thing you suggest.